# When is a queue preferable to regular linked lists?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, queue, abstract-data-type

In what kind of situation is it preferable to use a queue over a regular linked list? If the list is singly- or doubly-linked is inconsequential.

Comment: You can use a linked list to implement a queue. Perhaps that's what you're doing, without realizing it.

Comment: no because Im not taking the "rear" in consideration only a single starting node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **linear list** is a sequence of *n* nodes (possibly zero
nodes) where the essential structural property of the list is the
relative position between items as they appear in a line. Which
is to say, for any given node, we only care about its two
adjoining neighbours, i.e. the preceding- and the following
nodes.

We might want to be able to perform the following operations,

- Inspect the *k* th node of the list
- Change the value stored at the *k* th node
- Insert a new node before or after the *k* th node
- Merge two lists into a single list
- Split a list into two or more lists
- Make a copy of the list
- Get the length of the list (the number of nodes)
- Sort the nodes by some quality of the values
- Search the list for a particular value

Depending on the datums stored in the structure we are more
likely to perform certain operations more often than others
in our application.

Linear lists in which insertions, deletions, and accesses to
values occur always at the first or the last node is common, and
as such, they have been given special names.

A **queue** is a linear list for which all insertions are made at one
end of the list and all deletions and accesses are made at the
other end.

A **linked list** typically affords us a set of operations that
affords us the ability to traverse the entire structure and
perform operations on each node (and by extension, all of the
nodes).

The pair is distinguished from one another by the set of
operations they supply. The two are traditionally implemented in
different ways such that their respective operations are more
efficient.

---

A linked list is generally better suited for use-cases that
require read/write access to any node in the list.

A queue is better suited for what is known as [producer/consumer
situations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)
where the producer and consumer are interacting with the *data-structure* in an asynchronous fashion and where one wants to
consume items in the data-structure in the order in which they
were inserted, i.e. first in, first out ([FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_%28computing_and_electronics%29)).

Answer (score 0):

A queue is a particular organization of a linked list.  It is therefore practical to use queue when you want to imply that a queue is the best way to use your data.  For example, you may want to use a queue when you don't want a user to have access to data beyond the next item of the queue without first emptying it or if you want to order data by time of addition to the queue.

Comment: "For example, you may want to use a queue when you don't want a user to have access to data beyond the rear of the queue". There is no data beyond the rear of the queue, with respect to the data structure itself.

Comment: I meant the rear with respect to the link list, but I see why this might be confusing, especially depending on implementation.  I'll edit my answer for clarity